# Unit testing using Jest for React/Redux Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing my connected component using Jest.
This is how the component looks:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  onButtonClick(id) {
    dispatch(actions.onButtonClick(id));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onButtonClick} />
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  something: state.something
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

I am not sure how to test 'onButtonClick' since it dispatches an action. How to I expect dispatch to have been called with correct parameters using jest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is export your component in addition to the default export.  So change it to:

```
export class MyComponent extends Component
```

In your test,  you can now import your actual component instead of the connected component. As you have `dispatch` as a prop of your component,  you can supply a mock function or a spy (using something like jasmine or sinon) for `dispatch` in your test, and you can test if that gets called with the correct parameters.

Check out more on redux testing here:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html